# how to get script inside content see example below

Tags: javascript, xml

**I want to get content of script tag example**

**now see above in src property load bolo7.com content i want to catch that contain**
i have try so many method but it doesn't work

try 1 -> document.getElementById("data").innerHTML; //doesn't work

try2 -> document.getElementById("data").text; //doesn't work

if you are intelligent in javascript please give me answer that how to get content of script inside content

thanks in advance for your answer
my website is : http://www.bolo7.com/

Answer (score 0):

The *text* property defined by the [HTMLScriptElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-81598695) interface is the text content of the script element. If the element uses a *src* attribute, it should not have any content so its *text* property will be an empty string.

In that case, you will need to access the src some other way, perhaps XMLHttpRequest will suit.

Note also that the id attribute for script elements is not valid for the DOCTYPE being used at the linked resource (and the document is [invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.bolo7.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)).

Comment: Then you will have to get it some other way, such as via your server.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //some data here
        function add1(x) {
            return 1 + x;
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].innerHTML);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

but RobG is right, only works for inline javascript.